# Python : How to call a class methods(parent) in another class methods(child) only by importing class files(parent to child)?

Tags: database, python-2.7, inheritance, sqlite

I'm new to Python, as of now trying to develop framework for a product. in class file A i have written db access functions like insert, delete, select and update. in main class file i have to import all above functions and have to use class A functions.

so far i did below approach,
base class
    import sqlite3
    from sqlite3 import Error

```
class LocalDb:
    def insert_method():
       pass
```

have import insert_method to below class.
    from access_db.local_db.local_db import LocalDb

```
class Main():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def change(self):
        LocalDb.iterate_db()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.change()
```

when i tired above thing im getting "TypeError: unbound method iterate_db() must be called with LocalDb instance as first argument (got classobj instance instead)"

also. I have tried, Main(LocalDb) for inheriting the methods of LocalDd but im hitting an error says that "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: albums" (but in db we have "albums" table in db), here im getting confused when i use insert_db method within the LocalDb class file im getting the expected results.

here my questios are,

1. how to import class A methods in class B and how to call class A methods in class B?
2. if answer for the 1 question is inheritance(multilevel) then is there any other solution for the question no 1?
3. or am i getting confuse with inheritance and importing class methods to one class? or both are same?
4. even inheritance also what i did in second approach, i couldn't hit the iterate_db method(it throws error.) how to call the parent method in child class?

please some one help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

although your method does not get `self` as its first parameter (represents the class instance) it needs to be defined as a static method to be used without an instance of the class.

what you need here is a static method (assuming you do not need an instance of the `LocalDb` class available.

1. use `@staticmethod` decorator - [for docomentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod). 
   import the class with `from filename import LocalDb` and its methods will come with it.
2. irrelevent if we are using a static method.
3. irrelevent if we are using a static method.
4. for general knowledge here is the documentation of `super` - [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super), it is used to access the inherited class.

in summery the implementation of your code would look something like this:

```
class LocalDb:
    @staticmethod
    def insert_method():
       pass
```